# I have no libraries folder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My classmate have many libraries in 'libraries folder'. I have same libraries and have 'no libraries folder'. What is propblem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irMN0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPchy.png)

I tried changing my workspace. but It didnt work.

Comment: Your classmate imported them. Did you?

Comment: I guess they are using the Java EE perspective while you are using the Java perspective. These are just two different ways of showing the same thing. With your friend's installation, these are just grouped together.

Comment: Are you on the same Eclipse version?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the .metadata folder and it worked. When I replicate the old .metadata again, the same symptoms appear as before. I don't know the cause, but it has been resolved. Thank you everyone for your replies.